# How to use vite inside Laravel package

Tags: laravel, vite

I am building Laravel package locally and my package has views therefore I am using css and scripts. I decided to use vite but I am kind of stack because vite is looking for manifest.json in main Laravel public folder instead of inside the vendor and my package folder.

This is the error I am getting,

```
Vite manifest not found at: /Users/User/Sites/laravel-project/public/build/manifest.json
```

The way I am registering style and script in my package is like below

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

Comment: Delete build folder and npm run build again

Comment: I forgot mention that run cmd.exe as administrator and then run npm commands.

Comment: @ErcanE Were you able to sort out this problem? I have run into the same issue.

Comment: @Wallaaa I gave up. I am using mix now.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to pass the second parameter (which is the default):

```
@vite(['resources/css/critical.css'], config('vite.configs.default.build_path'))
```